# Twilio Chat API - get list of messages with pagination (pageNo, pageLimit )

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am unable to get the messages list using pageNumber and pageSize.
It returns the entire results everytime.
Is there any way to query the data by pageSize and pageNumber.

```
twilioClient.chat.services(TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .channels(req.params.id)
    .messages
    .list({
        pageSize: 2,
        page: 2
    }, (error, messages) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(error.status).json({
                message: 'Problem in getting messages',
                error: error
            });
        }

        if (Utility.isEmptyObject(messages)) {
            return res.status(404).send('Messages not found');
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Messages retrieved sucessfully',
            docs: messages
        });
    });
```

I would like to query the results by pageSize and pageNumber. Meanwhile if I send REST API call, it returns the results with pageSize but pageNumber is not working here also.

```
let limitCount = parseInt(req.query.limit > 0 ? req.query.limit : 10); // limitValue
let pageNo = parseInt(req.query.pageNo > 0 ? req.query.pageNo : 0);

let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/IS/Channels/' +
        'CH2f/Messages?Page=' + pageNo + '&PageSize=' + limitCount,
    headers:
    {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        Authorization: 'Token'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {

    console.log(body);

    if (error) {
        //console.error("There was an error loading the channels.", error);
        return res.status(error.status).json({
            message: 'Problem in getting messages',
            error: error
        });
    }

    if (Utility.isEmptyObject(response)) {
        return res.status(404).send('Messages not found');
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Messages retrieved sucessfully',
        messages: JSON.parse(body)
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to remove your access token from the question.

Comment: okay. thats not a valid token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio resources do not support page number based pagination. Instead a page of data will include `next_page_uri` and `previous_page_uri` properties. You can control the page size with the `PageSize` parameter.

When using the libraries, you can have them auto paginate for you. For example:

```
twilioClient.chat.services(TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
  .channels(req.params.id)
  .messages
  .list({
    limit: 400,
    pageSize: 100
  });
```

will ultimately call the API 4 times in order to return 400 total messages.

You can read more about [pagination of Twilio resources in the docs.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/twilios-response#response-formats-list-filters)

Comment: Also when using nodejs library, i am unable to get nextpage , previous page and other meta data fields but when using http request, all fields are displaying.

Comment: You can use the `page` method which will return a [`Page` object which has methods to get the next page and previous page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.27.0/Page.html)